# Double integral to calculate using Polar coordinate system?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I've met a double integral which seems to be calcultated in polar system.

$\iint_D \frac {y} {x^2+y^2} dxdy$ , where $D$ is the region bounded by the following conditions:

$-2y \le x^2+y^2 \le -4y$;

$\frac {x} {\sqrt3} \le y \le 0$

I am not sure how to use the circle $x^2+y^2$ to calculate the double integral.

Comment: You should write $dD$ at the end of this integral.

Comment: @Peter Foreman Sorry, it's typo, corrected.

Comment: Set $r^2 = x^2+y^2$, and $\frac{y}{x} = \tan\theta$.

Use the Jacobian $dx dy = r dr d\theta$.

Change the bounds to be in terms of $r, \theta$. Then crack on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the polar coordinate system;
$$x=r\cos{(\theta)}$$
$$y=r\sin{(\theta)}$$
$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$
$$dxdy=rdrd\theta$$
So the integral bounds are equivalent to
$$-2\sin{(\theta)}\le r\le-4\sin{(\theta)}$$
$$\frac1{\sqrt{3}}\cos{(\theta)}\le \sin{(\theta)}\le 0\implies -\pi\le\theta\le-\frac56\pi$$
Hence the integral becomes
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac56\pi}\int_{-2\sin{(\theta)}}^{-4\sin{(\theta)}}\sin{(\theta)}drd\theta
&=\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac56\pi}-2\sin^2{(\theta)}d\theta\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac56\pi}\left(\cos{(2\theta)}-1\right)d\theta\\
&=\left[\frac12\sin{(2\theta)}-\theta\right]_{-\pi}^{-\frac56\pi}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}}4+\frac56\pi-\left(0+\pi\right)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac16\pi\\
\end{align}$$